# How to setup nginx sites-available for aspnet core?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ssl, https, http

I've successfully hosted an ASPNET Core webapp using HTTP passing the

```
proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
```

to nginx, right now I'm having issues setting up the HTTPS, I've done `sudo certbot --nginx -d my.domain.com` and got this in my `/etc/nginx/sites-available-default`

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name my.domain.com;
    ssl_certificate /fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate /privkey.pem;
    include /options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /ssl-dhparams.pem;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

Ignore the paths I just couldnt copy the entire thing because Im using tmux in putty lol.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Wondering why you have ssl_certificate instead of ssl_certificate_key in your config for the key. What is your actual problem btw?

Comment: If I comment all the ssl/https settings and listen to port 80 I can visit my aspnet webapp, but if I enable https/ssl it wont even open up, cant browse my webapp with https

Comment: OK did you try add ssl_certificate_key instead. Also is nginx -t giving you errors and are there errors inside log?

Comment: ```nginx -t``` says it's fine, ssl_certificate_key, if I used certbot where can I find this key?

Comment: privkey.pem is the privkey

Comment: Oh yea sorry for the typos, ssl_certificate_key is pointing to the privkey.pem path correctly